# Is it possible to print a GoogleMaps via jQuery?

Tags: jquery, google-maps

I'm generating a GoogleMaps map in a dialog.

So, is it possible to print this map? I've seen that it's possible if only I render this map to an image format, something like a printscreen of the map. But, I have no idea how to do this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Static Maps API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/staticmaps/).  It generates a map image on the fly.

Answer (score 0):

Chris B is right, you want to do something like:

on Print (your "print this" click event or whatever)

**a**) Grab the current coordinates ,width, height and zoom of the currently displayed dynamic map (the one the user is seeing)

**b**) Replace dynamic map by an image tag and build your [static Maps API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/staticmaps/) Url  with the values you grabbed in **a**